# Проблема с событиями в DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, frontend, javascript-events

```
$('input').on('input', function(e) { 
//code
}
```

это события работает, когда в странице  старые открытые inputы, но если я добавлю новый input (т.е. не обновляя страницу) и введу внутри новый input этот события не работает, в чем проблема и как я могу это исправить?

Comment: Каким образом вы добавляете новый input?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('input', 'input', function(e) { 
  //code
}
```